# SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list in index.ejs while compiling ejs - although correct?

Tags: ejs

```
     <header>
            <% include templates/header.ejs %>
        </header>
            <% include templates/announcement.ejs %>
        <form>
            <br><input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search a fort...">
        </form><br>
        <section id="placeList">
            <div class="placeListBackground" id="placeListGet">
             <ul id="placeCells">
                <% placeData.forEach(function(placeData) { %>
                    <div class="placeContainer <%= placeData.category %>" class><a href = "https://www.roblox.com/games/<%= placeData.placeid %>/-"><img src= "<%= placeData.placeicon %>" alt="<%= placeData.placename %>" align="left" width="178" height="100"><span><%= placeData.placename %></span><p><%= placeData.clan %></p><p>Playing: <%= placeData.playing %></p><p class="sCategory"><%= placeData.category %></p></a></div>
                <% }); %>
             </ul>
            </div>
        </section>
```

I get an error saying "SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list in index.ejs while compiling ejs". Thing is, on my other computer this is exactly the same written code and works perfectly fine. Is it an issue with ejs or is there something I'm missing that may be significant?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to following suggestion. It works for me so it should work for you.

```
<%- include('./templates/header.ejs');%>
<%- include('./templates/announcement.ejs');%>
```